# How do I solve this system of linear equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

So when I graph $2x - y = 6$ and $x + 2y = -2$, I see them intersecting at points $(2,-2)$.

**HOWEVER,** when I set them equal to each other $(2x - 6 = -(1/2)x -1)$ I don't get $2$ for $x$. Can someone please clarify how to do this?

Comment: Change the title to reflect the actual problem.

Comment: How did you solve the second equation? The solution *is* $x=2$.

Comment: If you included your work, we could tell you exactly where you went wrong. Don't you think that would be extremely useful, rather than seeing people do things in their own (potentially very different) way?

Comment: Perhaps that's where my mistake is, but I have no idea on what part.

Comment: @john That's why you should show your work, so we figure out in what part you missed something.

Answer (score 2):

$\rm Method\,  I\,:Substitution$

We have the system:

$$
2x-y=6\tag 1 \\
x+2y=-2 
$$

From $(1)$:
$$2x-y=6\rightarrow y =2x-6\tag 2$$

Plugging into the second equation:
$$
x+2y=-2 \iff x+2(2x-6)=-2\\
5x-12=-2 \iff 5x=10 \iff x=2
$$

Plugging this back in $(2)$:

$$y=2x-6\iff y=2(2)-6\iff y=-2$$

$\rm Method\,  II\,: Setting\, equal $ (Don't know name for this):
$$
2x-y=6\iff y=2x-6\\
x+2y=-2 \iff y=-\frac x 2 -1\\
2x-6=-\frac x 2 -1\iff 4x-12=-x-2\\
5x=10
$$

Comment: Thank you, this is also another method, but I'm looking specifically for setting them equal to each other, not substitution.

Comment: @john Added.${}{}$

Comment: Thank you, it was a simple math error. I added an extra negative sign on my work while doing this.

Comment: No problem. Just remember, whenever you ask questions of this type (verifying homework exercises and such), post as much of your work as you can: It's much easier to help you that way (also, you will receive negative feedback if you don't, as people here want to help others learn, not solve homework!).

Answer (score 0):

Your method of solving the system of equations does work:
\begin{align*}
2x-6 &=-\frac{1}{2}x-1\\
2x+\frac{1}{2}x&=6-1\\
\left(2+\frac{1}{2}\right) x &=5\\
\frac{5}{2}x&=5\\
x&=5\cdot \frac{2}{5}\\
x&=2.
\end{align*}
Then just plug this value of $x$ back into either equation to solve for $y$.
If you want to clear the denominator earlier on:
\begin{align*}
2x-6 &=-\frac{1}{2}x-1\\
4x-12&=-x-2\\
4x+x &=12-2\\
5x&=10\\
x&=2.\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

You are correct till : $ 2x - 6 = {{-x}\over{2}} - 1 $

Maybe , you are solving it the wrong way .

$$ 2x - 6 = {{-x}\over{2} } - 1 $$

$$ \implies 2x + {{x}\over{2}} = - 1 + 6 $$

$$ \implies {{5x }\over{2} } = 5 $$

```
               DIVIDING BY 5 ON BOTH SIDES
```

$$ {x\over2} = 1 $$

$$ \implies x = 2 $$

Comment: How did you go from 2x + x/2 = -1 + 6 to 5x/2 = 5?

Comment: @john 2x + x/2 =  4x/2 + x/2 = 5x/2     ...... & on the right hand side  -1 + 6 = 6 -1 = 5

Comment: @Ricky Consider using `\implies` or `\rightarrow` instead of '$=>$'. It looks much cleaner.